# How to convert latitude/longitude to HTML5 coordinates without using Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation, coordinates

The goal is to use an array of coordinates to draw a route without using Google Maps. What is the best way to convert standard Latitude/Longitude coordinates to HTML5 canvas coordinates?

Comment: Have you looked at the Haversine formula? It will give you distance and angle, which you can convert to x, y easily.

Comment: I posted an answer that does it pretty well.

Comment: Note the weirdness that happens at the date line (i.e. 180th meridian). Fortunately, there aren't too many roads that cross it, currently only Fiji. But, depending on how large an area you want to deal with, you might need to code the special case where the shorter distance uses reversed coordinates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a fairly simple way to convert lat/lon to points.

1. Get the min/max coordinates of your set.
2. Have your canvas dimensions handy.
3. Use floating point calculation to get percentage of x and y on canvas.
4. Provide points to D3.

See JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/12stct3y/

```
var bounds = {
    "minLon": -81.267555236816,
    "maxLon": -81.261039733887,
    "maxLat": 28.979709625244,
    "minLat": 28.977783203125
}
var dimensions = {
    width:400,
    height:150
}   
function getX(x) {
    var position = (x - bounds.minLon) / (bounds.maxLon - bounds.minLon); 
    return dimensions.width*position;
}
function getY(y) {
  var position = (y - bounds.minLat) / (bounds.maxLat - bounds.minLat); 
    return dimensions.height*position;
}
```

Not included in fiddle:

1. Rotating to north-based view
2. Creating dimensions based on variable bounds

Comment: Hint: If you don't know the dimensions of the target, you can set the dimensions to 100*100 to get percentage which you can use in top/left css attributes with absolut positioning.